# How to install a bazelisk on macOS?

Tags: macos, bazel

I want to install Bazelisk as described here https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-bazelisk.html

It says `using a binary release for Linux, macOS, or Windows`

But how can I install that? should I download the darwin file? and then what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can install Bazelisk using brew

`brew install bazelisk`

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/bazelisk

This is the Github release page of theirs

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases/tag/v1.7.4

You can install it by

```
curl -Lo /usr/local/bin/bazelisk https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases/download/v1.7.4/bazelisk-darwin-amd64
```

And then

`chmod +x /usr/local/bin/bazelisk`

Now you can just run Bazelisk and it will always automatically give you the latest stable Bazel version:

`bazelisk version`

Comment: When I ran the command `bazelisk version` in a directory with a `.bazelversion` file, it downloads the Bazel version specified in the file.

Answer (score 0):

From Official Bazel Documentation

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/blob/master/README.md ->

Bazelisk is a wrapper for Bazel written in Go. It automatically picks a good version of Bazel given your current working directory, downloads it from the official server (if required) and then transparently passes through all command-line arguments to the real Bazel binary. You can call it just like you would call Bazel.

**Steps to Installing Bazelisk in Linux/Mac/Windows**

Below steps show installation of bazelisk v1.8.1, but you can install any desired version from https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases using same steps

**Steps for Bazelisk Linux Install**

```
> wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases/download/v1.8.1/bazelisk-linux-amd64
> chmod +x bazelisk-linux-amd64
> sudo mv bazelisk-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/bazel
     
# make sure you get the binary available in $PATH
> which bazel
bazel is /usr/local/bin/bazel
```

**Steps for Bazelisk Mac Install**

```
wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases/download/v1.8.1/bazelisk-darwin-amd64
chmod +x bazelisk-darwin-amd64
sudo mv bazelisk-darwin-amd64 /usr/local/bin/bazel
```

**Steps for Bazelisk Windows Install**

Download and install Bazelisk windows binary from https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases

**How to use Bazelisk and set desired Bazel version**

- If the environment variable `USE_BAZEL_VERSION` is set, it will use the
  version specified in the value.
- Otherwise, if a `.bazeliskrc` file exists in the workspace root and
  contains the USE_BAZEL_VERSION variable, this version will be used.
- Otherwise, if a `.bazelversion` file exists in the current directory or
  recursively any parent directory, it will read the file and use the
  version specified in it.
- Otherwise it will use the official latest Bazel release.